# Is it possible to make a diagonal pinstripe like this in CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible using only CSS (and no images) a background like the blue one in the following photo? If so, how?

[image]

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hd74keqq/

```
.striped-blue { background: #3777BB; padding: 20px;}
  .striped-blue p { color: #FFF; }
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Here is an article explaining how https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe its help you :)

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height:900px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  -55deg,
  #3777BB,
  #3777BB 1px,
  #3072B8 1px,
  #3072B8 6px
);
}
```

It is partially similar.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7n88m003/)

[image]

You can play with the properties to accommodate your need.

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height:900px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  -40deg,
  #3777BB,
  #3777BB 1px,
  #3072B8 1px,
  #3072B8 4.9px
);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7n88m003/1/)

[image]

**Edit:** Here you have more information of repeating-linear-gradient

**Formal Syntax:**

```
repeating-linear-gradient(  [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ,]? <color-stop> [, <color-stop>]+ )
```

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient)